# On representation of even integers as $a^x+b^y$

Tags: number-theory

Does there exist some $k \in \mathbb N$ such that for every even integer $n \ge k $ we can find positive integers $a,b,x,y$ such that $n=a^x+b^y$ , where $\gcd (a,b)=1 ; a,b>1$ and at least one of $x,y$ is more than $1$ ? I know that for every even integer $n>6$ there are integers $a,b>1$ such that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $n=a+b$ , so here  $x=y=1$ for every $n$ , I want to see if at least one power can be bigger.

Comment: Since you didn't post a proof for $x = y = 1$, it's because you can make $a = 2m-1$ and $b = 2m + 1$ for some $m$, and then $n = 4m$. You can hit $4m + 2$ by making $a = 2m - 1$ and $b = 2m + 3$.

Comment: For $n\ge 32$ looks good.  After that it seems you can always find the square of an odd prime lesser than $n$ to which $n$ is relatively prime.

Comment: And $31 = 3^3 + 4$; but $30$ can't be written in this form.  So $n \ge 31$ is the best bound you'll get.

Comment: @mjqxxxx : I am not looking for any "best" value of $k$ , rather I am looking for higher values of $x,y$ and I have no problem if $k$ is very large for that

Answer (score 1):

Let $n \ge 6$.  Choose a prime $p$ such $p^2 \le n-2$ and $p$ does not divide $n$.  Then $n=p^x+(n-p^2)^y$ with $x=2$ and $y=1$, and $p$ and $n-p^2$ are greater than $1$ and relatively prime.  This fails only if there is no such prime, which happens only if $n$ is divisible by every prime between $2$ and $\sqrt{n-2}$.  But in that case $n \ge \prod_{p \le \sqrt{n-2}}p$, which can't happen for very large $n$, since clearly the right-hand side grows much faster than the left.  Indeed,
$$
\prod_{p \le 7=\sqrt{51-2}} p= 2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7 = 210 \gg 51,
$$
so for $n\ge 51$ we can write $n=a^2+b$ where $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

Comment: by extension to the $5\#$ etc. cases, the last number to give trouble is actually $30$, and below that $24,18, 12, 10, 8, 6$ and down.

Comment: @mjqxxx : could you please post a proof that $\prod _{p \le \sqrt {n-2}} p > n , \forall n >51 $ ?

Comment: Sketch: It's true for $n=51$ by a factor of more than $4$.  Bertrand's postulate says there's a prime in $(x, 2x-2)$ for any $x>3$, so every time you multiply $n$ by $4$ or so, you pick up at least one more prime, greater than $7$, in the product.  So the right-hand side increases by a factor of $7$ each time the left-hand side ($n$) is increased by a factor of $4$, and we conclude that the inequality holds for all larger $n$.